# Watin Runscript No Wait

Tags: c#, visual-studio, watin

In Watin, as we have for `button.Click()` and `button.ClickNoWait()` methods. How can we have this for `ie.Runscript("Script")`.

In the script run actually a modal popup is opened, because `NoWait` or equivalent is not available I cannot handle the modal popup :(

Can anyone please suggest me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way you can get around this is to wrap your script code with JavaScript's settimeout() function and then run that via WatiN.

```
string timed = string.Format("setTimeout(\"{0}\", 500);", script);

Document.RunScript(timed);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I tried it, but no luck, because I am opening the modal popup. The next statement not executed until I close the popup.

Comment: That's interesting. I had the same exact problem and opening up with setTimeout() worked like a charm. The modal popup came up, but the execution of the WatiN script continued. This allowed me to attach to it and manipulate it.

Comment: This is actually also the code/solution which is used for ClickNoWait inside WatiN :-) Might add RunScriptNoWait in a future version to make this part of the public API of WatiN.